# VBA formula for cell in excel, inserting special character ambiguously

Tags: vba, excel-formula

I have a formula I am inserting into a cell in excel. After the formula is inserted it gives me a `#VALUE!` in the cell as an error. So when I inspect the formula I notice it is inserting an `@` in my formula. When I manually remove the `@` the formula works and returns a correct value.

The formula I am using in VBA is:

`=IF($E2="""","""",IF($F2=0,(LOOKUP(2,1/($H2:$M2<>""""),$H2:$M2))*$G2,IF($F2>0,INDEX($H2:$M2,MATCH(TRUE,""""<>($H2:$M2),0))*$F2+(LOOKUP(2,1/($H2:$M2<>""""),$H2:$M2)*$G2),"""")))`

and the formula looks like this after it is inserted in the cell: (Notice the @ character in the Match function)

`=IF($E2="""","""",IF($F2=0,(LOOKUP(2,1/($H2:$M2<>""""),$H2:$M2))*$G2,IF($F2>0,INDEX($H2:$M2,MATCH(TRUE,""""<>(@$H2:$M2),0))*$F2+(LOOKUP(2,1/($H2:$M2<>""""),$H2:$M2)*$G2),"""")))`

could someone explain why this is happening and maybe how to prevent it. this code is part of a larger code if you need more please let me know. thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Use `.Formula2` instead of `.Formula`.

Comment: ill try that now.

Comment: thank you for linking that other question. and Yes that did work and solved my issue. thanks